# Secure place to save access tokens?

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I'm developing a client as a UWP. 
I can handle the oauth login without problems but I'm not really sure where should i save the oauth access_token for the users. Is the ApplicationData.LocalSettings a secure place to store this type of information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Windows Runtime provides the PasswordVault class to securely store credentials.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx